# Diff function Flex

Tags: xml, apache-flex, actionscript

I am looking for a way to compare two XML files (old and new) and copy to an array all the nodes that are present in the new version but not the old version. I think it should be relatively straight forward to, for each node in the new XML file, iterate through the old XML file and see if it's found ... however, I do not think this is an efficient solution for large XML files (<10k nodes). I am wondering if there is a better solution - either algorithmic or function in Flex - to accomplish this task.

Thanks for all the assistance!

Comment: Personally, I think it's a horrible idea to even contemplate doing a diff on any text based data structure.  It's extremely inefficient and prone to error.  This kind of thing is normally done on the server end.  If this isn't possible, there are other solutions, but I need to know why you need to diff xml. Can you provide a sample of that xml?

Comment: This makes sense to be done for things like an Adobe AIR desktop application where you don't have a server. Also there is nothing about a "Server" that would make the task any less error prone?

Answer (score 0):

Jackson Dunstan has recently [tested XML performance](http://jacksondunstan.com/articles/1187) and found it indeed slow, even for access. Alternatives are nested Objects or Dictionaries containing XML data - but you must build them from XML once it is parsed, and this is not justified for a single pass. Or parse it yourself - but I'm not sure how much faster that would be, even with Alchemy.

Answer (score 0):

I'd look into algorithms which SVN merge tools use and use one those on the raw text, create an XML out of the diff and only parse that.